# Weblogic 503 errors on EVERY OTHER startup

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

We are having a rather frustrating issue wherein WebLogic takes its usual 3-5 minutes to deploy our application to a development machine (running Ubuntu 9.10 in my case) and then instantly gives us a 503 error when trying to access our application.  The odd part is that stopping the server and starting it always fixes the issue with no code rebuild of any kind.  I said that this occurred on "every other" startup but in fact it is more like 30-40% of the time we will get a 503, sometimes twice in a row but ussually it appears to alternate.

We have debugged our startup code on the application looking for any swallowed exceptions and have found nothing, our application just fails to start (silently).  By using the admin console we can reload the application and it will work as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Who is accessing who? what is the startup code you are talking about, what is it doing? Is the application really in a deployed state when accessed? Any logs to provide (maybe increasing the log level)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no idea why this was happening.  The domain was never fully starting, by using the WebLogic console to issue a start command I am able to make the domain actually finish starting without killing the server and starting over completely (which takes 5-6 mins).